# position: sticky breaks for tall content

Tags: css, css-position, sticky

I'm having some trouble getting `position: sticky` working for pages with (relatively) tall content.  Below I've set up a simple page with content simulated with a div that is twice the viewport height.  The sticky `.palette` tracks correctly with the page until the last couple dozen pixels when it falls off the top of the screen.

```css
body, html {
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #334;
}

.palette {
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 width: 300px;
 height: 20px;
 background: orange;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin: 10px;
}

.content {
 height: 200vh;
 margin: 10px;
 background: #556;
 border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="palette"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Neither using actual content, or setting the height of `.content` in pixels seems to change this effect.  The distance from the bottom at which the palette starts scrolling with the page seems to change with the viewport height.

**Why are my sticky divs not sticking correctly?**

Comment: Wrap your 2 divs in another div, probably has something to do with the item approaching the end of the container, if you increase the height of it, you will notice it will undck earlier

Comment: simply remove height:100% you are defining on html,body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position: sticky will only float over child elements and without a parent div it wont float over "content".

You can find a good explanation of how it works from [this medium article](https://medium.com/@elad/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap these two divs with a parent div.

Working Example:

```css
body, html {
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #334;
}

.palette {
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 width: 300px;
 height: 20px;
 background: orange;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin: 10px;
}

.content {
 height: 200vh;
 margin: 10px;
 background: #556;
 border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="palette"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
</div>
```